# HTML/PHP href Multiple Parameters

Tags: php, html, href, location-href

I've got this line of code:

`echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><a href='$row['type']/$row['id']/$row['wfurl']'>".($row['title'])."</a></td></tr>";`

What i'm trying to achieve is a href that directs to `/news/546/my-url-says-this`, the link is firing from the sites home directory. How do I put multiple PHP parameters in a href link? And how do i solve the `''` `""` issues i seem to be experiencing?

Comment: Concatenate, don't interpolate. Look, you're even concatenating `$row['title']` properly, so just do that!

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/GoZhv3

Comment: ah ha thanks, tbh i didn't even know you could concatenate in links like that ... learn something new every day eh :P

Comment: nothing to do with links, its all the same text to php, as its server-side, it does not know what a link is

Comment: Well you know me, bit of a fishy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to debug, try binding actual variables to the stuff you're pulling (I imagine you're pulling from a SQL DB with while($row = ...), right?).

So you'd have:

```
$type = $row['type'];
$id   = $row['id'];
...
```

Then try the echo with escaped double quotation marks and slashes and concatenation (what you're missing):

```
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"2\"><a href=\"".$type."/".$id."/".$wfurl."\">".$title."</a></td></tr>";
```

Comment: no reason here to waste resources creating extra variables.

Comment: True, it was for testing purposes only, to make it clear what his concat error was.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><a href='".$row['type']."/".$row['id']."/".$row['wfurl']."'>".($row['title'])."</a></td></tr>";
```